# Register a dependency, based on static property of other dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm sure I'm using the right terms, so it's probably best to resort to pseudo code.

A  dll has a type, without an interface and exposes the stuff I need through static properties. The code is pretty ugly.

```
public class ExternalType : IDisposable
{
   public static IOtherType PropertyINeed { get; set; } // also disposable

   public ExternalType(IOtherTypeFactory otherTypeFactory)
   {
        PropertyINeed = otherTypeFactory.Create();
   }
}

// in the registration I'd like to accomplish something along these lines
public class Service
{
   //...

   public void RegisterStuff()
   {
       Container.Register<IOtherTypeFactory>(() => new OtherTypeFactory());
       Container.Register<ExternalType>(() => new ExternalType());

       // Offending part: I need to have IOtherType registered with this 
       // implementation.

       // throws: Additional information: The registered delegate for type 
       // IOtherType returned null.
       Container.Register<IOtherType>(() =>  ExternalType.PropetyINeed)
   }
}
```

Since registrations and getting instances cannot be mixed, I'm wondering how to approach this scenario. I'm not at liberty to change the implementation of 'ExternalType', otherwise I would've done that :)

Comment: This seems really bizarre to me. But try: Container.Register<IOtherType>(() => { return  ExternalType.PropetyINeed;}"

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? I don't understand the question?

Comment: And why are you exposing dependencies as static methods?

Comment: And why would you initialize a static property in an instance ctor? And why ... ??

Comment: Yes, it is bizarre, but I can't change the implementation of the offending class to something nicer. If I could, I would :)

Comment: @Mik still Additional information: 'The registered delegate for type 'IOtherType' returned null.'

Comment: @Steven I need that specific IOtherType that gets instantiated by the constructor of ExternalType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is exibiting several code smells and anti-patterns:

- You use an Abstract Factory `IOtherTypeFactory`: [this is a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100), because a type should use the `IOtherType` directly instead of having to depend on two interfaces.
- The `public static IOtherType PropertyINeed` property is an implementation of the [Ambient Context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2007/07/23/ambient-context/) anti-pattern. The problems of this anti-pattern are very much related to the problems of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), such as:

  - The Dependency is hidden.
  - Testing becomes more difficult.
  - It becomes very hard to change the Dependency based on its context.
- The `PropertyINeed` property has to be initialized before use, and in your case the initialization is done by the construction of `ExternalType`. This causes [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).
- The `PropertyINeed` is static, which means `IOtherType` must be thread-safe as well, which is very unclear from this design. There are no safety nets in your code, nor can DI Containers help you to detect such issue because of the existance of this static property.
- The `PropertyINeed` is initialized over and over again, which can cause concurrency problems as well, especially when `IOtherType` changes under certain conditions.

The solution to these problems is *not* to store `IOtherType` in any static field and *not* to expose `IOtherType` from any class. Instead rely solely on **Constructor Injection** to inject `IOtherType` itself into *any* consumer that requires its use. Do not revert to Abstract Factories, Ambient Context or Service Locator.

If refactoring this at once is too hard, I would suggest doing the following as intermediate step:

```
var otherTypeInstance = new OtherTypeFactory().Create();

Container.RegisterSingleton<IOtherType>(otherTypeInstance);
Container.Register<ExternalType>();

// Set PropetyINeed Ambient Context with IOtherType singleton.
ExternalType.PropertyINeed = otherTypeInstance;
```

What changed:

- `ExternalType` doesn't depend on `IOtherTypeFactory` anymore.
- `IOtherTypeFactory` isn't registered anymore in the container: nobody needs to depend on it.
- The singleton `IOtherType` is created directly in the Composition Root using `OtherTypeFactory` and registered as 'single instance' in the container.
- The `PropertyINeed` Ambient Context is initialized at the end of the Composition Root using the earlier created instance.

Comment: Thanks. I love the suggestions, and I'm familiar with most, but I don't have the freedom to just change this. Lots of code depends on this.

Comment: Working with legacy software and legacy design can be hard. The very least I can advise is to -as an intermediate step- remove the `IOtherTypeFactory` dependency from the `ExternalType` constructor, and instead initialize `PropertyINeed` _exactly once_ from within your Composition Root (e.g. `RegisterStuff`) and add a Guard Clause to `PropertyINeed` that throws an exception when the value is requested when it is not set.

Comment: In a later stage, refactor its consumers one at a time. The typical solution is to inject `IOtherType` into the constructor of that consumer instead, but in case `IOtherType` is a cross-cutting concern, you might even want to refactor to decorators (which is typically an even bigger refactoring).

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm going to look in to this and I've scheduled a meeting to talk your prior points over.